# mysql innodb keeps getting corrupted

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

i have a mysql database on Mac OS. Theres one table with 700000 rows and a blob column. I use mysql workbench 6.3 (from XAMPP).

I have a sql script that simply updates my table like so:

update TABLE set X=Y where P=1

The script is about 100,000 lines long and EVERY LINE is of the form above. eg.

```
update TABLE set BLOB_COLUMN='Y' where P=1
update TABLE set BLOB_COLUMN='YA' where P=2
update TABLE set BLOB_COLUMN='SY' where P=3
update TABLE set BLOB_COLUMN='YC' where P=4
etc etc
```

I use the "source filename.sql" command to run my script.

My problem is that without fail on a certain line the process fails and leaves my database corrupted - then i have to trash it and restore from a backup. The exact output is below.

Ive done an innodbcheck and it tells me everything is fine.

Yes, it tells me the line number below and i could remove that line, but theres probably more lines later that could cause the same error.

Anyone know whats going on please?

Thanks

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 8021 in file: '1.sql': Lost connection to MySQL server during query
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 8022 in file: '1.sql': MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000) at line 8022 in file: '1.sql': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (61 "Connection refused")
ERROR at line 8022 in file: '1.sql': Can't connect to the server

No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000) at line 8023 in file: '1.sql': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (61 "Connection refused")
ERROR at line 8023 in file: '1.sql': Can't connect to the server

No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000) at line 8024 in file: '1.sql': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (61 "Connection refused")
ERROR at line 8024 in file: '1.sql': Can't connect to the server
```

Comment: Heres the line 8021:   UPDATE THE_TABLE SET blob_column='(dp1\nVBluewater\np2\nI1\nsVand\np3\nI1\nsVstores\np4\nI1\nsVare\np5\nI1\nsVhave\np6\nI1\nsVin\np7\nI1\nsVyour\np8\nI2\nsV!\nI3\nsVonly\np9\nI1\nsVhottest\np10\nI1\nsVfriendly\np11\nI1\nsVREISS\np12\nI1\nsV@\nI1\nsVyou\np13\nI1\nsVboys\np14\nI1\nsVnot\np15\nI1\nsVguys\np16\nI1\nsVWestfieldEast\np17\nI1\nsVgreat\np18\nI1\nsVhelpful\np19\nI1\nsVso\np20\nI1\nsVthe\np21\nI1\nsVclothes\np22\nI1\ns.' WHERE pkey = 8270;

Comment: Please post the error log of the server. I only see that errors of the client indicating that the server disconnected.

Comment: Increase the timeout.  I suspect that nothing is corrupted; rather all the inserts up to the timeout were "rolled back".

Comment: `Lost connection to MySQL server during query` isn't going to be a timeout issue... it likely indicates a server crash, particularly with the subsequent connect failures, suggesting hardware trouble (likely) or a payload-specific bug (not as likely).  There should be a crash and a stack trace in the MySQL error log.

Comment: hi folks, the error is in the log _somewhere_  but the logs is bbiiggg. so i thought id just run the script again and get the error from the log - but what-do-you-know it worked this time?! TBH, im going off MySQL, its good for inserting records but damn slow when retrieving and even slower when trying to delete records...